# How to parallelize a for-loop through a C++ std::set using OpenMP?

Tags: c++, set, openmp

I want to iterate through all elements in a `std::set` using OpenMP. Parallelizing a for-loop using `std::vector` is a fairly simple task. When working with vectors, I do the following:

```
std::vector<std::string> v = {"bla", "foo", "goo", "hoo"};
#pragma omp parallel for
for (unsigned int i=0; i<v.size(); i++) {
    // do something with v[i]
}
```

But what do I have to do if I want to loop in a parallel fasion through a set in C++? Using `std::set` instead of `std::vector` I use

```
std::set<std::string> v = {"bla", "foo", "goo", "hoo"};

std::set<std::string>::iterator it;
for (it=v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it) {
    // do something with (*it)
}
```

How can I parallelize this loop?

Comment: Is C++17 with parallel STL also an option?

Comment: @gast128 Yes, C++17 is an option.

Comment: @Samuel In that case, this should get you started: `#include <execution> #include <algorithm> std::for_each(std::execution::par, v.begin(), v.end(), [](std::string& str) { /* work with "str" */ });`

Comment: @TedLyngmo When I try to use `#include <execution>' I get the following error: `fatal error: execution: No such file or directory`. I use the g++ compiler version 8.3.0 and Linux.

Comment: @Samuel Ok, if I remember correctly, the 8.3 line of g++ didn't have that C++17 feature. g++ 9.x does.